# CMV integration with Nearmap

Tags: configurable-map-viewer, nearmap

Has anyone integrated Nearmap imagery into a CMV application?  Have you utilized a Tiled Map Service (TMS), WMS or something else?  Have you run into any problems with a need for credentials especially if incorporated into a public application?

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion on github about using Nearmap as a basemap in CMV [here](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/issues/619).

That issue doesn't discuss authentication. Using your Nearmap credentials to create a time-limited authentication ticket are described [here](https://support.nearmap.com/hc/en-us/articles/212920057-Authenticate-to-Nearmap-with-a-ticket). You would need to create server-side code using something like ASP.net or PHP to acquire the ticket that would then be used within CMV's configuration.